# foreign key: conflicted with foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

so i have 2 tables related to each other with an fk

```
appointment
  {id, dept.id, datetime, sometable.id, sometableagain.id}
task
  {id, appointment.id, deptlead.id, taskname}
deptlead
  {id, name}
```

so i had to alter the appointment table to another foreignkey from another table. so i dropped the keys (task_appointment_fk, appointment_sometable_fk, appointment_sometableagain_fk) altered the table to add the new field and added again everything. the last two got added with no problems. while the other one (task_appointment_fk) kept giving me a this message :

```
"ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the Forien Key Constraint "dept_appointment". The Cconflict occurred in the database "MyDb" , table "appointment", column "id"
```

so i found some solutions that states that there might be some rows on the task that has a appointmentid value that does not exist on the appointment table. so i tried inserting rows that would have the same value right. still gives me the same thing. the thing is , i want to delete the rows from the task to make it easier but doing that i have to drop all the fks again and do the same thing all over on the other tables, and i have a lot of other tables..

need some advice.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query to see which values in foreign key table does not have a matching key record in primary key table .If values are there then try to delete them .

```
select   * from     [task] a
left join [appointment] b
 on       a.appointment_id = b.id
```

Comment: yeah i read that somewhere. the problem with that is, like i said, there's several fk connected to those fks as well. if i do that, it'll  be hard to retrieve them and get them mapped again.